# How to get the YearNum as columns and total, group by MonthNum from below table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

From the above table, how I've to get the total for each year in different columns group by monthnum, I mean MonthNum, TotalIn2013,TotalIn2014,TotalIn2015

Output should be like second table:

[image]

Comment: `TotalIn2013` means Sum for all months in 2013??

Comment: No, for each month group by MonthNum

Comment: Just add a sample for your expected outout for better understanding

Comment: PIVOT?   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: My output should be like second table

Comment: Again PIVOT, this is one of the most repeated topic here.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,monthnum, case when (yearnum = 2013) then sum(total) as [totalIn2013]
when (yearnum = 2014) then sum(total) as [totalIn2014] 
when (yearnum = 2015) then sum(total) as [totalIn2015] from tablename
end
group by id,monthnum
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this from your sample:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE 
(
  YearNum INT 
, MonthNum INT
, Total BIGINT
)

INSERT INTO @t (YearNum, MonthNum, Total)
VALUES (2013, 11, 15100)
, (2014, 11, 117100)
, (2014, 1, 64000)
, (2014, 2, 59600)
, (2015, 1, 224150)
, (2015, 2, 191660);
```

Use the PIVOT Function to achieve what you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM @t
PIVOT (
    SUM(Total)
    FOR YearNum IN ([2013], [2014], [2015]) 
) p
ORDER BY MonthNum
```

If the years you want to display are dynamic, you would need to come up with dynamic sql, recursive CTE or some smart apply.

Answer (score 0):

Use MS SQL PIVOT  [technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx](http://PIVOT?%20technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) 
It' quite enough if every month has at least one row for at least one year. 
Otherwise you may need to PIVOT a LEFT JOIN of inline tally table for months to your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT Id,
        MonthNum, 
        CASE WHEN (YearNum = 2013) THEN SUM(Total) END AS Total2013
        CASE WHEN (YearNum = 2014) THEN SUM(Total) END AS Total2014
        CASE WHEN (YearNum = 2015) THEN SUM(Total) END AS Total2015
 FROM TABLE      
 GROUP BY Id, MonthNum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a dynamic sql query also.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);

select @sql = 'select MonthNum,' 
        + stuff(
            (
               select distinct ',sum(case YearNum when ' 
               + cast(Yearnum as varchar(4)) 
               + ' then Total else 0 end) as TotalIn' 
               + cast(Yearnum as varchar(4))
    from your_table_name
    for xml path('')
), 1,1, '');

select @sql += ' from table_1 group by MonthNum;';

exec(@sql);
```